# Display ManyToManyField in a template in Django

Tags: django, database, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have the following models in my project (in my project one site can have many payment processors and one payment processors (Paypal, Payza, etc) can belong to many sites).

```
# Models.py
class Sites(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class PaymentProcessors(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=75)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Sites_PaymentProcessors(models.Model):
    site = models.ManyToMany(Sites)
    payment_processor = models.ManyToMany(PaymentProcessors)
```

View:

```
 # View
 def home(request):
 site_list = Sites.objects.order_by('-date_launched')
 processors_list = PaymentProcessors.objects.all()
 return render_to_response('index.html', {'site_list': site_list, 
                                          'payment_processors_list': processors_list}, 
                                           RequestContext(request))
```

Template

```
 # Template
 {% for site in site_list %}
     {% for payment_processor in payment_processors_list.site.all %}
          {{ payment_processor }}
     {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}
```

I'd like to display all payment processors which belong to an specific site. I tried to use filters but I can't do it work. I'm new to Django, I tried to read the documentation and see some answers on StackOverflow, but I'm not sure about what I have to do to it works properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need that intermediate table in your models, django will build that for you behind the scenes.

```
#models.py
class PaymentProcessor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=75)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Site(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    payment_processors = models.ManyToManyField(PaymentProcessor, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And then in the view you just need to get the site_list, because you can get the payment processors from the site object:

```
#views.py
def home(request):
    site_list = Site.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html',
        {'site_list': site_list})
```

Finally in the template you loop through the ManyToMany object with the all function, and there ya have it!

```
#index.html
{% for site in site_list %}
    {{ site }}:
    {% for p in site.payment_processors.all %}
        {{ p }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```